# Why is black grease oozing from my Makita circular saw?

Tags: repair, circular-saw

I have a Makita 5007MG circular saw. I noticed black grease oozing out of it and I believe it is coming from the arbor bearing but am not sure.

Comment: We're not sure either. Please revise to provide a better description or photos.

Comment: Sounds like a blown seal or possibly the motor overheated.  I had a house fan that did that and it was caused by the motor overheating when my son ran the fan 24/7 for a week in temperatures over 100 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: what do you mean "oozing"? Does it mean you noticed a small bit of grease near the arbor? Or that grease is pouring out of the saw and being flung everywhere by the blade?